# Package Frontespizio don't modify fixed names

Tags: thesis, frontespizio

I'm using package `frontespizio` to format the frontespiece of my thesis.
I was trying to modify the style and size of the fonts used in the standard frontespiece through the environment `Preambolo*` as following

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{frontespizio}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}, tableposition=top, figureposition=bottom, font=small}
\usepackage[autostyle, italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, hyperref, babel=hyphen, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossario}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{frontespizio}
\begin{Preambolo*}
\renewcommand{\frontinstitutionfont}{\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\frontdivisionfont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\rmfamily}

\renewcommand{\frontpretitlefont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape}

\renewcommand{\fronttitlefont}{\fontsize{20}{24}\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\frontfixednamesfont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape}

\renewcommand{\frontnamesfont}{\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\frontsmallfont}{\fontsize{9}{11}\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\frontfootfont}{\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries}
\end{Preambolo*}

%other commands like \Universita{...} etc. 
\end{frontespizio}

[...]

\end{document}
```

The problem is, the line `\renewcommand{\frontfixednamesfont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\scshape}` don't seem to work as i expected: the `fixed names` (Relatore, Candidato ...) first takes the same style as set in line `\renewcommand{\frontnamesfont}{\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries}` (which means that in this specific case they will be in bold), and then superimpose the style in `\renewcommand{\frontfixednamesfont}` (`\itshape` in this case), resulting in a bold italic style in this case. I tried various combinations, the result is the same except for styles like `\rmfamily` that are completely substituted by `\frontnamesfont` style.

I searched on `frontespizio` documentation, but i wasn't able to find anything relatable to this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem but if you do not want the fonts to combine you can start each definition with `\normalfont` eg `\renewcommand{\frontfixednamesfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape}`  will always give the same font no matter what font is current at the point the command is issued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the default definition of `\frontfixednamesfont`, you see

```
295 \def\frontfixednamesfont{\normalfont\normalsize\front@font}
```

(line number added for clarity), where `\front@font` does `\normalfont` unless the `sans` option has been issued, when it does `\sffamily`.

So if you want to change the font for the fixed names, you have to say

```
\renewcommand{\frontfixednamesfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape}
```